# openpyxl insert image in chartsheet

Tags: openpyxl

Using openpyxl an image can be inserted in a workbook using:

```
img = openpyxl.drawing.image.Image(img_name)
img.anchor = 'D2'
mywb.add_image(img)
```

see: [Insert an image into Excel with openpyxl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51953494/insert-an-image-into-excel-with-openpyxl)

But when I try to insert an image in a chartsheet:

```
img2 = openpyxl.drawing.image.Image(img_name)
img2.anchor = 'F12'
mychart.add_image(img)
```

the error is: AttributeError: 'Chartsheet' object has no attribute 'add_image'

Is it possible to insert an image in a Chartsheet?
Any suggestions for workarounds?

Many thanks in  advance

Comment: Can't be done with openpyxl.